# Chapter Headings Vertically Centered

Tags: header-footer, vertical-alignment, chapters

I need your expertise for something ;) I would like to have the "Chapitre" vertically centered compared to the number of the chapter. Here's what it is looking right now :

[image: chapter headings]

This is the code I use to make it look like on the picture :

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\Large\centering}
  {\begin{adjustbox}{angle=90}
\hbox{\scshape\chaptertitlename}\end{adjustbox}\ 
\fontsize{150}{60}\selectfont\color{gray}
{\fontfamily{Domitian-TLF}\selectfont \bfseries\thechapter}}{15pt}{\bfseries\Huge}
```

(The number "1" of the chapter use the "Domitian" font).

Thanks in advance for your help!! (Sorry for my bad english by the way)

Answer (score 2):

After I completed your MWE by adding `\begin{document} chapter title and text \end{documernt}` it only compiled with erros such as `\color` being undefined and problem with the `\fontsize{150}{60}` not available and `size <24.88>` being substituted.

However, you can raise the `\chaptername` typesetting like this:

```
% chaptitleprob.tex  SE 567408

\documentclass[11pt, a4paper,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\Large\centering}
  {\begin{adjustbox}{angle=90}
\hbox{\hspace{1em}\scshape\chaptertitlename}\end{adjustbox}\ 
\fontsize{150}{60}\selectfont%\color{gray}
{\fontfamily{Domitian-TLF}\selectfont \bfseries\thechapter}}{15pt}{\bfseries\Huge}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Symmetries}
\end{document}
```

by putting some space before it. In my MWE `\hspace{1em}` seems to work OK.

[image]